# tslint:disable not working properly

Tags: javascript, eslint, tslint

I'm using VSCode, and have TSLint plugin installed. Apart from this I also have `eslint` configured for my app. However, for one line, I'm trying to disable `eslint` with the below code.

```
if (!Intl) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require no-global-assign
  Intl = require('intl')
}
```

However, when I run my linter it still shows an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the eslint plugin for vscode installed? Are you using a eslint config file? How are you running the linter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn out that when specifying multiple rules a `,` is required in between the rules.

```
if (!Intl) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line global-require, no-global-assign
  Intl = require('intl')
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually with vs code, you can just put your cursor on the offending line and type `Ctrl + .` and the ide will add the appropriate rule.

the syntax you are looking for is `// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length`

Comment: What if i'm using just Javascript and not typescript?

Comment: sorry, i read the `TSLint` part of your question and assumed typescript.